# What does 'Trivial' refer to when considering Linear Independence?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my college textbook a set of vectors (S) is described as being:

- Linearly Dependent if zero vector is non-trivial Linear Combination of elements in S
- Linearly Independent if only trivial Linear Combination yields zero vector

I do not understand the use of the term 'trivial' here, could someone please explain to me?

Comment: A trivial linear combination is one in which all the coefficients are $0$.

Comment: Which textbook are you using? The trivial linear combination should be defined in it, if it is not then it's not much of a textbook...

Comment: related: [What does 'trivial' refer to..?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4253727/21813)

Comment: @5xum yep, it's the textbook specific to the course and they don't mention it anywhere.....

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you